# Turning multiple pre-created Android activities to a single activity with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

As a preamble; I have an Android app containing 4 activities, and I wish to transfer these into a single activity containing Fragments (two extending `ListActivity`, and two extending `Activity`), with navigation between Fragments enabled by a Navigation Drawer . I have attempted to turn these Activities into ones extending `ListFragment` and `Fragment`, however much of the code within the activity ceases to function: for example, `getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)`, the `unbindService` and the 'registerReciever', and primarily the different `onCreateOptionsMenu`s contained within the disparate activities.

Therefore I ask, would it be possible to port any separate Activities to a single fragmented  one, but still retaining the same function as with the separate focused activities, with minimal editing?

Also, regarding the transition process would one need to end a previous Fragment within the main Activity to display another Fragment in the same space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, fragments have a very similar lifecycle to activities ([See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)). You'll find it is probably a case of copy/paste from your activity classes to your fragment classes with very minor tweaks to have them work as they were as separate activities. The only legwork you will have to do is swapping these fragments from your activities.

For example, an activity with its onCreate function that looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Find views
    homeMessagesButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeMessagesButton);
    homeCreateMatchButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeCreateMatchButton);
    homeMyMatchesButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeMyMatchesButton);
    homeMyTeamsButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeMyTeamsButton);
    homeSquadButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeSquadButton);
    homeSettingsButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeSettingsButton);

    // Set click listeners
    homeMessagesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeCreateMatchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeMyMatchesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeMyTeamsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeSquadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);    
}
```

Will now look like this in a fragment (note the fragment uses the onCreateView lifecycle method to inflate its view inside the activity the fragment will appear in)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);     

 // Find views
    homeMessagesButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeMessagesButton);
    homeCreateMatchButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeCreateMatchButton);
    homeMyMatchesButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeMyMatchesButton);
    homeMyTeamsButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeMyTeamsButton);
    homeSquadButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeSquadButton);
    homeSettingsButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homeSettingsButton);

 // Set click listeners
    homeMessagesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeCreateMatchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeMyMatchesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeMyTeamsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeSquadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
```

Changing fragments within the activity is done through the use of the fragmentTransaction manager as shown in the android training site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Since your service requires to be bound to a activity, rather than a fragment. This becomes trivial as fragments can retrieve the activity they are bound to. For example, the code below used in a fragment will automatically get the activity they exist within.

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving your code from Activity is fairly simple. For example [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater%29) is also available in Fragments and as for your methods that require a context or Activity, you can call [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) from your Fragment to get a reference to the parent Activity.

EDIT : to replace a Fragment, there's also [a method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) for that from the FragmentTransaction class, taking the id of the container View in argument.

Comment: What of the Android functions such as `bindService`, which, when the activity is translated to a fragment, become undefined for the .class?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by "become undefined for the class", but bindService is a method of Context, you can call that as well on getActivity ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) in your fragments you need to use the context of your activity. Context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE). Some methods work on Activities and if you want to use them elsewhere you need to get the context.